# Default value on Bundle.getString(String key)

Tags: android, bundle

I've just noticed that, while most of getters from a `Bundle` have the possibiliy of including a default value, in case the key doesn't exist in that particular bundle instance, `getString` does not have that possibility, returning null if that case.

Any ideas on why is that and if there is some way of easy solution to that (by easy I mean not having to check each individual value or extending the `Bundle` class).

As an example, right now you have only this:

```
bundle.getString("ITEM_TITLE");
```

While I would like to do:

```
bundle.getString("ITEM_TITLE","Unknown Title");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to wrap it yourself:

```
public String getBundleString(Bundle b, String key, String def)
{
    String value = b.getString(key);
    if (value == null)
        value = def;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: That was what I thought. But the idea of extending Bundle still seems a bit messy. I guess I will stick with checking every time for the moment :)

Comment: @trojanfoe, how to do it for boolean? `value == null` is always false for a boolean value.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB You'd probably use [`Bundle.getByte()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#getByte(java.lang.String)) instead.

Answer (score 36):

Trojanfoe has the best solution if that is what you want, though once you get into dealing with defaults for other datatypes you'll have to do the same thing for them all.

Another solution would be to check to see if the bundle contains the key:

```
String myString = bundle.containsKey("key") ? bundle.getString("key") : "default";
```

It's not as nice as a function, but you could always wrap it if you wanted.

Comment: This will not work if the key exists but is of a different type (check my answer for an alternative). However, it will work if you are sure the key will either contain a `String` or not exist at all, in which case it's a shorter solution (1 line vs 2 :P).

Comment: It's true, but I was just thinking it was assumed to be a string.  So, don't use this method if you don't know what the data addressed by the key in this bundle will be :)

Answer (score 10):

Note: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

`public String getString (String key, String defaultValue)`

Since: API Level 12

EDIT this function has moved to BaseBundle: [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: This looks ideal, however this function returns null for me.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to check for `null`:

```
String s = bundle.getString("key");
if (s == null) s = "default";
```

This is better than csaunders' solution because the `Bundle` can contain the respective key but it can be of a different type (for example an `int`), in which case his solution would result `myString` in being `null`, instead of `"default"`.